What to choose between Right Right rotation and Right Left Condition in AVL Tree while balancing
I have this AVL tree:
 5
  \
  15
 /  \
10  20

The parent Node 5 is the disbalanced node, and both conditions of rotation are present:

Right Right Rotation from 5-15-20
Right left Rotation from 5-15-10

So which one to choose and why as we can perform rotation for both the conditions?

There are four possible variants of balance violations that can occur during the standard operations on an AVL tree. As Wikipedia also lists:

Let X be the node that has a (temporary) balance factor of −2 or +2. Its left or right subtree was modified. Let Z be the child with the higher subtree (see figures 2 and 3).
[...]
There are four possible variants of the violation:

Right Right ⟹ Z is a right  child of its parent X and BF(Z) ≥ 0
Left Left   ⟹ Z is a left   child of its parent X and BF(Z) ≤ 0
Right Left  ⟹ Z is a right  child of its parent X and BF(Z) < 0
Left Right  ⟹ Z is a left   child of its parent X and BF(Z) > 0


So here the categorisation leaves no doubt. There is no overlap, and each category has a corresponding rotation to perform.
In your example tree,  is the root node that has a balance factor of +2.  is its right child. So we are in scenario 1. This scenario needs a simple rotation to the left, where  becomes the left child of :
  15
 /  \
5    20
 \
  10

Although you could perform a double rotation, by first rotating the subtree rooted at node 15 to the right, and only then perform a rotation to the left at the root node, this just adds work: there is no need to perform a rotation at node 15. A simple rotation at the root is enough.
